# Why does an await within a server endpoint blocks other incoming requests?

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I have two different versions of an endpoint for testing.
The first one is this:

```
app.get('/order', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("OK")
    getPrintFile()
})
```

And the second one is this:

```
app.get('/order', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("OK")
    await getPrintFile()
})
```

the getPrintFile is an async function that returns a promise when every operation is done. Withing the function I upload an image to a
server, I download a new image, and re upload that new image to another server.

I noticed that in the first example, without the await, if I send a lot of requests to the "order" endpoint,
I get the "OK" instantly for each request, which is what I want because that "OK" will get replaced by a res.status("200"). I need
to send a status 200 immediatly after getting the endpoint hit for various reasons. Then I don't care how long it takes for the server to do all the processing of the images/uploading, as long as the res.send(200) is executed instantly when there is a new incoming request.

However, when I use the await, even if new requests are coming in, it takes a lot to display the next "OK" if a previous request
is still processing. Usually it displays the OK only when the code within the getPrintFile function is done executing (that is, images are uploaded and everything is done)

It's like the event loop is blocked but I don't understand why.

What is happening here?

Edit:
So it is clearer, I tested it. If I send 5 requests to the "order" endpoint, the "OK" is displayed in the console immediately for all of them, and then the images are processed and uploaded at their own speed for each request. In the second example, if I send 5 requests, the first OK is displayed, and then the remaining 4 are displayed one at a time when the previous request is done executing, or if not exactly in that order, they get logged with tremendous delay, and not consecutively

Comment: But from the given example, both cases console.log will execute first, so if your res.send() back to the client before the getPrintFile() function then I don't see any issues here. If I'm not correctly understand then please update the question with bit more detailed code example. Thanks

Comment: @JijoAlexander No they don't. I tested it, in the first example, if I send 5 requests, the "OK" is displayed in the console immediately for all of them, and then the images are processed and uploaded at their own speed for each request. In the second example, if I send 5 requests, the first OK is displayed, and then the reimaing 4 are displayed one at a time when the previous request is done executing, or if not exactly in that order, they get logged with tremendous delay, and not consecutively

Comment: In response to your edit:  `getPrintFile` does what, exactly?  (If you replace it with a dummy `getPrintFile` that does nothing, do things get fast again?)  My point is that the code you provided does not reproduce the behaviour you described.  Your question would be vastly improved if you provided an actual minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer based on my understanding of your problem. The first thing missing is the `res.sendStatus(200)` in your examples to make them actually work. But then, indeed it happens as you describe it: the `/order` endpoint actually is "blocking" you from making another request as the `await` is blocking you from reaching the final statement (res.send). Here a full example

```js
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

async function takeTime() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("resolved");
      resolve(1);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

app.get("/order", (req, res) => {
  console.log("ok"); // Happens immediately
  await takeTime();
  return res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("ok"); // Happens immediately
  takeTime();
  return res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("server running on port 3000");
});
```

When testing the API (i.e. from Postman), you won't be able to run immediately another request on the `/order` endpoint, because you will be locked in waiting for the answer of the request just sent.

In the `/` endpoint, on the other hand, you will receive immediately the `HTTP 200` response (as there is no await) and the code for the `takeTime` function will keep running asynchronously until it's done.

[Here](https://nodejs.dev/learn/modern-asynchronous-javascript-with-async-and-await) you can find more information, I hope it's useful.

##### Edit 1

here I add the .html page I'm using to test the `await` loop requests

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body></body>

  <script>
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      fetch("http://localhost:3000/order");
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

The fetch is not working for me in the browser, but having a web page making those request works

Comment: That is precisely what I was looking for. The link was also very valuable. Thank you.
So, correct me if I'm wrong, it is not bad practice not to resolve a promise if we want to run a function asynchronously. And now that I think about it, it is not super wise to put an await directly within an endpoint, because if whatever the await is waiting for takes a long time to resolve, then every other request is blocked?

Comment: It actually depends, sometimes you want to have the `async` in your endpoint. Let me make an example: let's suppose that you want to retrieve some information from the database. The operation itself is asynchronous, but you need to wait for the result to give it back in the response, so you have to `const result = await Model.find(...)` and then `res.send(result)`

Comment: I see now! The only doubt left is, why doesn't node just create a new instance of the /order endpoint every time a new request comes and doesn't run all of those instances separately from each other at the same time? Why do I need to manually remove the await so that new requests don't get blocked?

Is it because, say, in an example where whenever the /order endpoint is hit, it changes some text stored in the database, and returns that text to the customers, I'd maybe want each customer to get the most recent version of the text and so I would have to block the endpoint using await?

Comment: It actually work like that! Every request is evaluated separately and you don't have to wait for the others. If you test them on Postman you may experience such issue as by default it will wait the previous response. But try for example on a snippet inside and HTML page and send 10 request (without awaiting for the response) inside a for-loop `for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) { fetch("http://localhost:3000/order") }` (consider that you have a maximum of 6 connections that can be in the state of PENDING at the same time in some browsers) and you will see that the "ok" will happen instantly

Comment: mmm I tried it but it actually doesn't. If I do this in the chrome console: for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) { fetch("http://localhost:3000/order") } then it behaves in the blocking way, where I get "ok" "resolved" "ok" "resolved" and so on but if i call the other endpoint for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) { fetch("http://localhost:3000") } then it behaves in the non blocking way, where "OK" is displayed 10 times in a row and then the promises are resolved. Am I missing something? Could you try it out to see if you get the same?
I'm talking about the "ok" that gets displayed in the backend console

Comment: I edited my answer to add the html page code that I'm using to have non-blocking request for the `await` case

Comment: Hi. I don't wanna drag this on, you already helped me a lot. I'm not sure I explained myself correctly tho. Make 3 consecutive requests to the "/order" endpoint and look at the console on your backend terminal. What I see is "ok" "processed" "ok" "processed" "ok" "processed". Instead, if I send the same 3 requests using the "/" endpoint (where no await is used) what I get is "ok" "ok" "ok" "processed" "processed" "processed"... can you explain to me why that is? That's what I have been trying to understand